# hide tr that has th and colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alter the background of "table tr" if it has a "colpan" and if it contains "th" but this below wont work.

```
$("#mytable tr").contains('th').attr('colspan').hide();
```

Can you help?'

Comment: Note that `attr('colspan')` will return a String, not a jQuery object, so calling `hide()` on the String is not going to work.

Comment: Also, for `.contains()` I think you meant to use [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/), since the only version of 'contains' is [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) (a selector that looks for a *string* within an element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("#mytable th[colspan]").parent().hide()
```

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the `<` selector? It's one I've not seen before, and doesn't *seem* to feature on the [jQuery Selector page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I know that this is not there because i have discovered it 4 minutes before.Seriously i am also in doubt why it is working but it is

Comment: I love that you managed to randomly find an undocumented jQuery selector..! The downside is that the undocumented has a tendency to disappear or stop working, if the jQuery internals are changed, of course.

Comment: @hello-world don't use `<` selector

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
$('#mytable tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).has('th[colspan]').length;
    }).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dJPvX/1/).

Edited to add the `.length` to the filter, since finding an empty array counts as finding something, in jQuery...sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('th[colspan]').parents('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go sir:

$('#mytable  > tbody  > tr> th[colspan]').hide();

that will hide the all **th** which have **colspan** attribute from **mytable**.

please don't forget to vote up.

:)